# Change Asp.net controls visibilitiy in page load with string controlnames

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some different controls in my page like Button, Textbox maybe Gridview..
In page load i ll set their visibility and enabled properties. But i ll have only their id's like string.
From database i ll take

```
   ControlId  Type     Visible   Enabled

   btnSave    Button      0         0

   txtEdit    TextBox     1         0
```

Do u have any idea how can do that in my page load?

Comment: Have you tried FindControl(id)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Comment: The controls are created dynamically? Where?

Comment: You can loop through the form controls set properties accordingly.

Comment: @amartynov when use find control i cant change Enabled property. But for visible it works.

Comment: @SirajMansour sorry i was very busy. Thank u..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say you have your control ids loaded into a string[]

Try :

```
protected class ControlDescription
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isVisible { get; set; }
        public bool isEnabled { get; set; }

        public ControlDescription(string _name, int vis, int ena)
        {
            this.Name = _name;
            this.isVisible = (vis == 1);
            this.isEnabled = (ena == 1);
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ControlDescription> CDescriptions = new List<ControlDescription>();
        //loop through data from database 
        //{
        //ControlDescription C = new ControlDescription(name,int,ena);
        //CDescriptions.Add(C);
        //}

                foreach (ControlDescription C in CDescriptions)
                {
                    Control Ctrl = this.FindControl(C.Name);
                    if (Ctrl != null)
                    {
                        //Ctrl.Visible = C.isVisible;
                        DisableControls(Ctrl);
                        //if (Ctrl is WebControl)
                        //    ((WebControl)Ctrl).Enabled = C.isEnabled;
                        HideControls(Ctrl);
                    }
                }
    }
```

EDIT :
Based on your comment you may not know the type of your control is not always a webcontrol or not a subclass necessarily, i added 2 more functions and used them in the code up there instead of the existing code.

```
private void DisableControls(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{

    foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in control.Controls) {

        // Get the Enabled property by reflection.
        Type type = c.GetType;
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Enabled");

        // Set it to False to disable the control.
        if ((prop != null)) {
            prop.SetValue(c, false, null);
        }

        // Recurse into child controls.
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0) {
            this.DisableControls(c);
        }

    }

} 

private void HideControls(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{

    foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in control.Controls) {

        // Get the Enabled property by reflection.
        Type type = c.GetType;
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Visible");

        // Set it to False to disable the control.
        if ((prop != null)) {
            prop.SetValue(c, false, null);
        }

        // Recurse into child controls.
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0) {
            this.HideControls(c);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Great way of bifurcating the task into simple parts, best reusability

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple method to find page controls and set the properties something like below.

Note: I have not compiled the code.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SetControl("txtEdit","ASPxTextBox",1,0);
    SetControl("btnSave","ASPxButton",0,0);
}

private void SetControl(string controlId,string controlType, bool visible, bool enabled)
{ 
    foreach(Control control in Page.Controls)
    {
        if(controlType == "ASPxTextBox" && control is ASPxTextBox && control.Id == controlId)
        {
            var tb = ((ASPxTextBox)control);
            tb.Visible = visible;
            tb.Enabled = enabled;
            break;
        }
        if(controlType == "ASPxButton" && control is  ASPxButton && control.Id == controlId)
        {
            var bt = ((ASPxButton)control);
            bt.Visible = visible;
            bt.Enabled = enabled;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u Deepu. But my controls can be Devexpress control.
ASPxButton, ASPxTextBox, ASPxCheckBox... i ll use it in my all project. So i cant use like that.

Comment: @CocLn In that case, you can modify the if condition like ASPxTextBox instead of TextBox. Can you debug the code and see

Answer (score 0):

Thank u @Siraj Mansour for that reply  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422753/1685288

Firstly with webcontrol i couldnt find. But later with your solution it works. And i have panel in my page. So with this.FindControl i cant find my controls which are inside a panel. So i changed your finding with;

```
Control Ctrl = FindControlRecursive(Page, c.Name);
```

and i wrote a recursive method;

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string controlId)
    {
        Control ret = null;
        if (root.ID == controlId)
        {
            return root;
        }
        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, controlId);
            if (t != null)
            {
                ret = t;
                return ret;
            }

        }
        return ret;
    }
```

and DisableControls method;

```
   private void DisableControls(System.Web.UI.Control c)
    {
       Type type = c.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Enabled");
        if ((prop != null))
        {
            prop.SetValue(c, false, null);
        }
    }
```

Really thank u. If u can think best solution for this i ll change.

Comment: This is the most neat i could think of :) Happy coding !